# why swagger not associates description to $ref when converting annotation to yml

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, readme

I'm having a use case where I'm using multiple variables of same class type, when using like this description provided in @Schema of variable level is overriding . How to avoid this and any work around without creating new class for each variable?

Eg:

```
Class Response
    {
        @Schema(description = "Description 1")
        private TypeA variable1;
        @Schema(description = "Description 2")
        private TypeA variable2;
    }
```

even though we gave description in yaml $ref was only there and in UI in all the variable description it is showing Description 1

I tried reproducing oneOf workaround through java annotation and is not working, I don't want to create new class for every variable I'm using for the same class Type. Any other work around will be more helpful